# (Rails) Validate polymorphic association based on its parent record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord, shrine

I have an `Upload` model for fileuploads that is shared among other models  with polymorphic associations.

```
# upload.rb
class Upload < ApplicationRecord
  include ImageUploader[:image]
  include VideoUploader[:video]
  include BackgroundUploader[:background]

  belongs_to :uploadable, polymorphic: true
end

# product.rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :uploads, as: :uploadable, dependent: :destroy
end

# announcement.rb
class Announcement < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :uploads, as: :uploadable, dependent: :destroy
end

# site.rb
class Site < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :uploads, as: :uploadable, dependent: :destroy
end

...
```

`Upload` is hooked to different [Shrine](https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine) uploaders, such as `ImageUploader`, `BackgroundUploader` or `VideoUploader`, to upload and process different filetypes. In order to do so, Upload has different columns for each filetype, such as `image_data`, `video_data` or `background_data`.

Now, the associated "parents" of an `Upload` should only support certain filetypes. When associated to…

- `Product`, it should only allow Image and Video uploads
- `Announcement`, it should only allow Image uploads
- `Site`, it should only allow Background uploads

**How can I validate the `Upload` model based on the association with its parent record? Should this validation happen in the `upload.rb` or in its parent models?**

In terms of code, `Upload` should only allow the respective fields when associated to a parent. Something like…

```
if upload.parent == product
  validate presence image_data xor video_data

if upload.parent == announcement
  validate presence of image_data

if upload.parent == site
  validate presence of background_data
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails/issues/61
Maybe this helps u out

Comment: Shrine has support for validation https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine#validation

Comment: @ImreRaudsepp thanks, this helped. I found a working solution inspired by your post. Using `validate :field, absence: true, if: Proc.new { |r| r.uploadable.instance_of? ModelClass }` I can make a conditional validation if the record's parent is an instance of a specified class. To me it seems more obvious to make these conditional validations on the level of the `Child Model`. Any opinions on that?